# Model Many to Many relations with Abstract Class

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models.py

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Domain name'), unique=True)

class Company(Institution):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()


class HC(Institution):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    bed_count = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have the models that are generated from Institutions and I want to follow the Institutions from the Profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    about = models.TextField(_('About'), blank=True, null=True)
    following_profile = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, null=True)
    following_institution = models.ManyToManyField(Institution, blank=True, null=True)
    following_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to make M2M relations to all models that inherits Institutions. Is there a way to do this with Generic Relations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're ready for polymorphism:

https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org

Otherwise you'll have to add them individually, so your Institution model would look something like this:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Domain name'), unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and the manytomany just basic like this:

```
following_company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True, null=True)
following_hc = models.ManyToManyField(Institution, blank=True, null=True)
```